# Document version management

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, version, document

I am working in sharepoint site. In this site there is a user requirment where user want see the version numbers maintain by sharepoint in its OOB versioning feature in a document itself.

SO as the document ge modified sharepoint maintains the version number for each updation.
User want to see that vesion number in that document itself as a text.

Can anyOne tell me Is it possible in sharepoint..? If yes the what will be best approch ro do it..?

Can I use document parser in this case..?

Thansks in advance
Sachin